# Vbscript: How to filter those values within a range but not found in an array collection?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript

In the code provided below, I have a test array. I want to look up for those values which are within the range of 400 to 500 but not found in the Test array
(`Ex: 410 - Although this value is in the range of 400 to 500, it is not found in the array`)
Once I find it, I need to add it to a new collection and perform new action (like `set the value of it to 410|New-value`) to display on the webpage.

Here is the code:

```
Test= Array("1|Name", "2|Place", "400|Animal", "420|Thing")

For Each x in Test
    xSplit=Split(x,"|")
    'Do Something'          
Next    
    'Do Something'
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have key/value pairs there, so the appropriate data structure is probably a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each x in Test
  xSplit = Split(x, "|")
  dict.Add xSplit(0), xSplit(1)
Next
```

That way you can easily check if a key value is present or not:

```
If dict.Exists(42) Then
  WScript.Echo dict(42)
Else
  WScript.Echo "Index 42 does not exist."
End If
```